# Continuously moving data from aws aurora mysql to aws s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-kinesis, amazon-aurora, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I am trying to setup data lake and move all the data to s3.
I have to move aurora mysql data to s3 (most probably in parquet format).
I tried initial POC using Data Migration Service with that we can move all data at once. Problem with this was every time I run it will copy whole data.
I wanted something like near real time reflection of db changes in s3.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you enable binary logs you should be able to do Change Data Capture and replicate ongoing changes as explained at [this blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/replicate-data-from-amazon-aurora-to-amazon-s3-with-aws-database-migration-service/)